# Nude model in Thailand

Tags: travel, models, contracts, nude-photography

I am going to travel to Thailand at the beginning of October. I will get to see this beautiful country and hopefully take some nice shots of it. I do have some hours of spare time, which I'd like to spend photographing a thai model (I literally love how they appear in pictures).
Provided that I do have a bit of experience on nude photography (let me be clear: -not cheap porn-), I would like to ask you a couple of questions:

- Does anyone have any experience with Thai models' culture? Is there something that I may or may not do that could look not polite to them?
- What is my best option (ModelMayhem seems not to be helping much) to find an experienced, trustworthy model, without having anything to do with prostitutes (this may sound offensive, but I'm actually striving to search for models, but escorts are all I can find)?
- Will a "normal" commercial contract work, or do I need any "special" sentences to be written on it?

Comment: You could try emailing famous photographers from Thailand and seeing what modelling agency they use? I wouldn't imagine you would need anything extra in the contract, maybe something stipulating how you would protect the models anonymity? As some people get rather private when it comes to nude photography. I would also make sure that your contract is properly translated into the local dialect so that it can be properly understood by your model.

Comment: Well imagine that you'd receive an email from a non-"your language"-speaker, which would like to know stuff about your pictures... First of all it would sound to me like spam (I doubt also that if the photographers are famous, they would reply anyway), in the second place I may be concerned about the security of the models. About the contract... Well English is pretty international and when it would come to find a notary to translate it... I would have a problem more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some links:

Modeling agency: 
http://www.famemgtasia.com/

Similar and very useful thread: 
http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/558133-session-with-an-amateur-model/

Basically Noldor, without having been there previously (I've been twice but only as a tourist) it's a little hard to imagine but it's extremely easy to get it handled once you are there.

You can ask at the hotel travel arranger or if you are brave you could probably ask one of the local "house moms" if they have anyone who is good in front of a camera.  People in Thailand are extremely accommodating and eager to assist.

But do check out the thread as well... it has lots of "good to know" kinds of advice particularly around some potential legal pitfalls.